# I need to move Button left-right and then again left-right using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to move button once left-right. But I need to move it 2 times i.e   left-right and again left-right.

Here is code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    sayNoVisual(100);
});

function sayNoVisual(px) {
    $('.stepback').animate({
        'marginLeft': px
    }, function () {
        $('.stepback').animate({
            'marginLeft': 1
        });
    });
}



  <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="stepback"  runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Call the function twice? With a timeout.

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){sayNoVisual(100)},3000);`

Answer (score 0):

- You can recursive function in `animate` callback
- To increase value you shoud use `"+=" + value`

**CODE**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    sayNoVisual(100, 2);
});

function sayNoVisual(px, r) {
    $('.stepback').animate({
        'marginLeft': "+=" + px
    }, function() {
        if(--r > 0) sayNoVisual(px, r);
    });
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XaDh5/)**